# Excel VBA - Application.Match method not finding match

Tags: excel, vba, matching

I have a small macro program that matches values between two worksheets (big data).

I'm using **Application.Match** method to find the match of a certain value in another worksheet.

The problem is, when I try to assign a row variable on the range, the result gets **Row 1** instead of **Row 7** where the exact match is.

Application.Match(data1, Worksheets("Data").Range("O" & **lRowRange** & ":O" & lLastRow), 0)`

```
lRowRange = 5

If Not IsError(Application.Match(data1, Worksheets("Data").Range("O" & lRowRange & ":O" & lLastRow), 0)) Then

     lMatchFound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(data1, Worksheets("Data").Range("O" & lRowRange & ":O" & lLastRow), 0)

     sDataFound = Sheets("Data").Cells(lMatchFound, 15)

End if
```

I'm not using LOOP statements to find the match because the worksheets contain large amount of data.

Hope you could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Can you troubleshoot with a smaller data set, say just 10 row and then work out if there is a match or not? You have not posted enough information to provide a meaningful answer. Is there a match? How do we know?

Comment: Sorry. Yeah. the program is working great, it's finding the exact match. The only difference is, I changed the default starting range to an actual variable which is lRowRange=5. It's like Range("O5:O10"). But the result = 1, which is weird and I don't know why.

Comment: I'll bet *lRowRange* is 4 when that happens. match doesn't **always** return the row on the worksheet; it returns the **position within** the lookup range. So if your lookup range doesn't start at row 1 on the worksheet, you have to adjust the returned value by the starting row of the lookup range. In your case, Match is returning 1 (the first row in the lookup range) and you were expecting 4 so the first row of the lookup range (i.e. *lRowRange*) must be row 4.

Comment: tldr; Match + lRowRange -1 = row on worksheet.

Comment: btw, you can pass the return of Application.Match to a variant type var and test the variant with IsError so you don't have to Match twice.

Comment: apologies. updated my post. it should be Row 7 instead of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a match in O5:O10. If your searched text is in O5, then your match function give you a '1', because it is found in the first cell of your range.

Use

```
sDataFound = Sheets("Data").Cells(lMatchFound + lRowRange - 1, 15)
```

and you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Appreciate you help.